# Why does print-circle default to nil?

Tags: printing, lisp, common-lisp

CLHS says

```
An attempt to print a circular structure with *print-circle* set
 to nil may lead to looping behavior and failure to terminate.
```

And then there's this:

[Why does this Lisp macro as a whole work, even though each piece doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657481/why-does-this-lisp-macro-as-a-whole-work-even-though-each-piece-doesnt-work)

Apparently, having `*print-circle*` set to nil leads to surprises. Why is `*print-circle*` set to nil by default on many systems? What can go wrong if I set it to t globally right from the beginning of my code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you set `*print-circle*` to true, then all your output functions have to do cycle checking. That means they may slow down and take more memory.

If you don't actually use circular structures (and I'm not a Lisp pro, but I tend to avoid them like the plague), I wouldn't turn cycle checking on in production code.